# Como fazer get do city name no plugin geolocation ngcordova?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho um app móvel com o plugin `ngcodova` de geolocation esta a funcionar só que só com `lat` e `long` o que pretendo agora e que o mesmo invés de me dar a `lat` e `long` me dei-a o nome da cidade como posso fazer ?

**Controller**

```
.controller('GeoCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation) {
var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
$cordovaGeolocation
  .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
  .then(function (position) {
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude
      var long = position.coords.longitude
      alert(lat + " --- " + long);
  }, function(err) {
    // error
});
})
```

Comment: Caso voce use mapa, como a google, voce pode usar https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Answer (score 0):

Envie latitude e longitude para este endereço, daí é só tratar o retor em JSON [Georeferenciamento Reverso](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=-18.163044&lon=-47.9435387&format=json&json_callback=my_callback)